# Creating a form in React that saves data

Tags: javascript, json, forms, reactjs, state

I am trying to create a customer details form in react (currently using react-json-form) where I can reuse the values in the inputs to create a saved file that the app can refer to. I have created the form and can output the results but I am unsure how to save the input values for future use or call them back once they are saved.

If anyone has any suggestions or examples of a form that does this then I would be greatly appreciative.

My code is as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import JSONTree from 'react-json-tree';
import { BasicForm as Form, Nest, createInput } from 'react-json-form';

const Input = createInput()(props => <input type="text" {...props} />);

const UserFields = () => (
  <section>
    <h3>User</h3>
    <div>Name: <Input path="name" /></div>
    <div>Email: <Input path="email" /></div>
  </section>
);

export default class ExampleForm extends Component {
  state = { data: {} };

  updateData = data => this.setState({ data });

  render() {
    return (
      <Form onSubmit={this.updateData}>
        <Nest path="user">
          <UserFields />
        </Nest>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        <JSONTree data={this.state.data} shouldExpandNode={() => true} />   
      </Form>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more simple solution would be to use a form, like a semanti-ui-react form, store the information to the state onChange, then convert the info to JSON for storage.

```
import { Form, Button } from 'semantic-ui-react'

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()

    this.state = {
      name: "",
      email: ""
    }
}
handleChange = (e, {name, value}) => {
  console.log(name, value)
  this.setState({[name]: value})
}
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Form onSubmit={this.sendDataSomewhere}>
        <Form.Field>
          <Form.Input name="name" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
        </Form.Field>
        <Form.Field>
          <Form.Input name="email" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
        </Form.Field>
        <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
       </Form>
     </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I use a dynamic method of receiving the input from different fields using the name and val attributes. The values captured in state are then accessible by `this.state.whatever`

Hope this helped

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising.

Only problem seems to be that when I try to use the code it gives me the error unexpected token and points to:

" this.state = {"
 
Would you happen to know what is causing this?

Comment: Whenever you start typing in the field it will change the state.